# CSS positioning branding issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to achieve the branding appearance (where the brand overlaps the navbar) found here - http://logobro.com/our-work

However I seem to have missed the CSS rule(s) to help me achieve this, as you can see in the website here: http://www.bestcastleintown.co.uk/port/

Here is my current styling for `.brand`

```
.navbar .brand {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 200;
    line-height: 1;
    margin-left: -20px;
    padding: 8px 20px 12px;
}
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an issue with your margins and paddings, instead of `padding: 8px 20px 12px;` try:

```
padding: 12px 20px 0px;
margin-bottom: -4px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS:

```
#topbar-logo
{
  margin-bottom: -3px;
}

.brand
{
  padding: 0px;
}
```

This will archieve exactly the same effect as on your sample website.